# Convexity/ Concavity preserving under integral

Tags: integration, probability-theory, convex-optimization

In Boyd and Vandenberghe's book ``Convexity Optimization'', page 79, it is said that convexity is preserved by nonnegative weighted sums, and can be extended to integrals, say, if $f(x,y)$ is convex in $x$ for each $y \in \mathcal{A}$, and $w(y) \geq 0$ for each $y\in\mathcal{A}$, then $$ \int_{\mathcal{A}} w(y)f(x,y) dy $$ is convex in $x$.

Now my problem is, is there any restrictions on $\mathcal{A}$, such that convexity is preserved? For example, if the integral limit contains functions of $x$, that is, if the boundary of $\mathcal{A}$ can be expressed as $h(f(x,y))$, is convexity still preserved or under what restrictions on $h(.)$, will convexity be preserved?

By a comparison, Kalin (1968) terms a `total positivity'' to a concavity preserving rule. I don't know how to understand this and is`total positivity'' of the density function related to my question?

Comment: ${\cal A}$ is a fixed set. It is not clear what you mean by 'the boundary of ${\cal A}$ can be expressed at $h(f(x,y))'. Perhaps you could elaborate by example.

Comment: @copper.hat That is what exactly I am concerned with. I an wondering the case when the size of $\mathcal{A}$ depends on $ x $.  For example, $y$ is uniformly distributed in $[0,1]$, so $w(y) = 1$. But what if we consider the integral space is $\mathcal{A} = [0, h(x)] \subset [0,1]$ where $0 < h(x) < 1$? If convexity (concavity) if preserved, do we need restrictions on $h(x)$?

Comment: I don't understand, is $A$ a fixed set or dies it depend on $x$? If the latter then the result doesn't apply.

Comment: @copper.hat Oh I see. $\mathcal{A}$ is not fixed and depends on $x$. So where can I find some properties regarding convexity/concavity preserving operations like this? Are there some textbooks or papers that I can refer to?

Comment: That's a pretty open question, you would need to be more specific...

Comment: Sorry, that's a little hard to read. (I often create a comment in an answer box just to get the formatting correct and then cut & paste it over.)

Comment: In any event, I need to go to sleep!

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks for your help. I am trying to check the concavity of the following: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2588191/is-an-expectation-of-a-concave-function-still-concave   I don't know whether there is any other properties to check the concavity, except for checking the sign of the second order derivatives.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71167/discussion-between-randy-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Oh, if $\mathcal{A}$ depends on $x$, all bets are off, and B&V's statement does not apply. (oops, copper.hat said that already)

Comment: If $A : = A(x)$ changes in affine way then convexity is guaranteed .  Because using change of variable you can make $A$ a fixed set and induce it's affine effects on integrant function.